# Segmentation Fault after slightly modifying my code

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'll copy the relevant lines:

(Declarations)

```
typedef struct { /* per una entrada de la taula de posicion */
    int f;
    int c;
} pos;
pos *p_opo[9];
```

(in main)

```
for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        p_opo[i] = (pos *) calloc(n_fil * n_col / 2, sizeof (pos)); 
    }
```

Now, after only having introduced this lines, the code breaks in an arbitrary point (in a call to a given library function). I suspect I'm corrupting something with this, although I don't know what.

All I want is to have an array of variable size arrays!

PD: num is an argument of the program. I've been running it with num=1 anyway.

Comment: Edited the post. num is an argument of the program. I'm executing this with num = 1 right now and getting the error.

Comment: if num <= 9, I don't see any problem with what you wrote down.  What do you mean with "the code breaks in an arbitrary point"?

Comment: It breaks in a call to a library function which has been working fine until I modified this. What's even worse, that function doesn't even mess with p_opo!

Comment: If num is an 'argument to the program', are you getting that from argv?  Are you converting the character representation of num from argv to an int using atoi?

Comment: is it a compile or runtime error, if so, what is the error?  that kind of useful information...  Also, the function/code that is called when the error occurs...  Have you used a debugger?

Comment: try running in a debugger... that would help more.. or probably try using valgrind for memory leaks..

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code you've posted. You might check the code that uses p_opo[], you might be walking off the end of the array.

Comment: You are stepping on memory somewhere. Physically move the line where you define '*p_opo' to a different location and something else will break. You need to figure out what it is that's altering memory where it shouldn't be.

Comment: The problem is that this is homework. I'm compiling and executing all of this in a Solaris remote machine via ssh. I can't install a debugger nor there is none installed already. I've tried to "migrate" the code to my computer, but I'm missing some custom libraries my teachers have installed on the machine which I can't access. All what I can do is to compile and execute. 

@steabert: run error. I can see the "segmentation fault" error on the console for a second and then the console gets closed.

Comment: you can try to copy a debugger from your system to the remote system

Comment: What is n_col and n_fil? There's nothing wrong with the code there, we'd need to see more of the code

Comment: n_col and n_fil are the dimensions of the screen. I'm trying to get my code back to the state in which it worked right now. I'll keep you updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

num should be less or equal to 9. (0..8 allocated pointers in p_opo equals 9 !)

Note that in C that you get errors in a different place in case of memory leaks, etc. The reason for this is that by changing some code, other code or data can be rearranged and this may end up in segmentation faults.

So the problem may very well be in another part of your program. Make sure you have all you warnings turned on (like the -Wall option in gcc), it may give you some clues.

Comment: num=1 for my tests. That is exactly what I mean with "breaking in an arbitrary point". I've already have the -Wall option turned on. No errors nor warnings when compiling...

Comment: @Hallucynogenyc Run your program from gdb. When you get a Segmentation fault, use the 'bt' (backtrace) command to trace where things go wrong.

Comment: no gdb installed, nor can I install it. read above to know why.

Answer (score 1):

If your call to `calloc` asks for memory of size `0` it may return `NULL`, and if you are making use of that memory it could be causing the segmentation fault.  So if:

```
 0 == (n_fil * n_col / 2)
```

or somehow

```
0 == sizeof (pos)            /* I don't think that this is possible */
```

the size of the memory that you are asking for is 0, and so calloc can return NULL.

If this is not the case then I don't think that you have enough code up there for anyone to know why it is segfaulting.  You should keep in mind that errors like this can go unnoticed until you add or change some code that seems to be totally unrelated to the code that has the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing you casting the return of `calloc` makes me suspicious. Don't do that, this leads to a typical error if you forget the include for the system function.

This happes if you are on a machine with 64 bit pointers and 32 bit `int`.

Comment: @Hallucynogenyc: Sure without the cast you have the same error. The idea is that without it any decent compiler should give you a frank warning. I suppose you compile with `-Wall` or something like that? And that you don't have any warning at all from your compiler?

Comment: that is. So I can safely keep the cast where it was?

Comment: you really shouldn't do casts. this is not C++